# Flutter : error in line 25 apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk, flutter-provider

i am import the project flutter for git hup and problem happened

update the verisen kotlin

and happend this proplem

Build file 'D:\tataboq_app_final-master\android\app\build.gradle' line: 25

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> org/gradle/api/services/BuildService
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spN0O.jpg)
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JYCb.jpg)

if you want more picter or cod i am sent that

Comment: its difficult to suggest anything without code